# How we can fetch data faster in oracle 9i by using select command between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM retailer_master r,
     dlymtd d
WHERE r.retle_no = d.sender_mobile
AND r.fos_no = '"+1234567890+"'
AND d.amount IN ('5.00', '9.00', '11.00', '13.00', '14', '15', '15.05', '16', '17', '18', '21', '22', '23', '26', '31', '34', '35.01', '37', '38', '42', '45', '53', '57', '59', '61', '76', '79', '89', '92', '96', '97', '99', '102', '145', '148', '159', '194', '199', '249', '299', '549')
```

It is taking lots of time to give output.

Comment: It highly depends on the size of the data set you are working with, and structure of the tables

Answer (score 0):

Please try to create index on retle_no and sender_mobile and check the performance.
Hope this will help you